# Eclipse IDE Find/Replace Wildcard

Tags: eclipse, replace, find, wildcard

I'm trying to replace parts of my code in a file that all have quotation marks around them.  They look like this:

```
public static Map<String, String[]> "acidspray" = Map.ofEntries(
public static Map<String, String[]> "acrobatics" = Map.ofEntries(
    etc.
```

I wanna be able to just remove the quotes around the variable names. I've tried looking up how to use wildcards in the Find/Replace feature, but either I'm not understanding it or my situation is different than what I've been seeing. Some help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a Regular Expression find/replace for that - so check the "Regular expressions" check box in the dialog.

The find string could be:

```
"(\w+)" =
```

which finds a `"` followed by one or more word characters followed by `" =` and captures the word characters. I have included the `=` to restrict the match to just assignments.

The replace string:

```
\1 =
```

`\1` uses the word characters captured by the find pattern, followed by the `=`.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes perfect sense.